# Difference between OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor and MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in netty

Tags: java, netty, nms

While writing netty application I am not sure to which thread pool should i use for my pipeline handler.

either I should go with

```
// OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor impl
    OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor pipelineExecutor = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(
            200, 1048576, 1073741824, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new NioDataSizeEstimator(), new NioThreadFactory("NioPipeline"));
```

or

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(
     16, 65536, 1048576, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
     new MyObjectSizeEstimator(),
     Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
```

Not sure about the difference  between two.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is pretty clear started in the javadocs. The OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor will ensure events are executed in "order" for a Channel, while MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor does not.